# list::sort changes the values c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting

I've written a simple algorithm in c++ that doesn't work. I discovered that when I sort a list of pointers to objects from a custom class I've made, they change. Or more accurately, the list changes to weird random objects from that class.

```
// ConsoleApplication45.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>  
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;  

class LocationNode;
class NodeMap;


class LocationNode
{
private:
    char name;
    int xLocation;
    int yLocation;
    //map<LocationNode*,int> neighbors;
    LocationNode* neighbors[100];
    int neighborWeight[100];
    int neighborCount; 
    LocationNode *previous;
    int score;

    int CalcDistance(LocationNode &dest)
    {
        return (int)sqrt(pow(dest.xLocation-xLocation,2) + pow(dest.yLocation-yLocation,2));
    }

public:
    int finalScore;

    bool operator<(LocationNode const& rhs) const
    {
       // Use whatever makes sense for your application.
       return (finalScore < rhs.finalScore);
    }
    bool operator==(LocationNode const& rhs) const
    {
       // Use whatever makes sense for your application.
       return (name == rhs.name && xLocation == rhs.xLocation && yLocation ==rhs.yLocation );
    }

    LocationNode(char name, int x, int y)
    {
        neighborCount = 0;
        this->name = name;
        this->xLocation = x;
        this->yLocation = y;
    }

    string GetPath()
    {
        if(previous!=NULL)
        {
            return string(1, name).append((*previous).GetPath());
        } else {
            return string(1, name);
        }
    }

    void Connect(LocationNode &other, int weight)
    {

        this->neighbors[neighborCount] = &other;
        this->neighborWeight[neighborCount] = weight;
    }

    void CalcScore(LocationNode &previous, LocationNode &dest)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborCount; i++)
        {
            if(neighbors[i] == &previous)
            {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        score = previous.score + neighborCount[&index];
        finalScore = previous.score + neighborCount[&index] + CalcDistance(dest);
    }
    void CalcNeighbors(LocationNode &dest)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborCount; i++)
        {
            (*neighbors[i]).CalcScore(*this,dest);
        }

        /*for (pair<LocationNode,int> node : neighbors) 
        {
            node.first.CalcScore(*this,dest);
        }*/
    }

};

bool my_compare (LocationNode* a, LocationNode* b)
{
    return a->finalScore < b->finalScore;
}




class NodeMap 
{
private:
    static LocationNode& str;
    static LocationNode& dest;
    static LocationNode* node;
    static list<LocationNode*> nodes;
    static void loop(bool isFirst)
    {
        if(isFirst)
        {
            node = &str;
        }
        (*node).CalcNeighbors(dest);
        nodes.sort(my_compare);
        node = nodes.front();
    }
public:
    static string start()
    {
        Init();
        loop(true);
        while(node != &dest)
        {
            loop(false);
        }
        return dest.GetPath();
    }
    static void Init()
{
    nodes.clear();
    LocationNode A ('A',1,2);
    nodes.push_back(&A);
    LocationNode B ('B',7,1);
    nodes.push_back(&B);
    LocationNode C ('C',2,8);
    nodes.push_back(&C);
    LocationNode D ('D',4,3);
    nodes.push_back(&D);
    LocationNode E ('E',9,6);
    nodes.push_back(&E);
    LocationNode F ('F',1,2);
    nodes.push_back(&F);
    A.Connect(B,2);
    B.Connect(D,3);
    D.Connect(E,2);
    E.Connect(F,3);
    A.Connect(C,1);
    C.Connect(F,10);
    dest = F;
    str = A;
}
};

LocationNode& NodeMap::str =  *(new LocationNode('A',1,2));
LocationNode& NodeMap::dest = *(new LocationNode('F',1,2));
LocationNode* NodeMap::node =  &str;
list<LocationNode*> NodeMap::nodes;



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << &(NodeMap::start());
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

before sort
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPMPU.png

after sort
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj9nA.png

Sorry that I cant post the images directly here I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Where did you learn to use the Microsoft monstrosity `_tmain` (now nearly 20 years after it last was even relevant for anything), and why did you post it on SO?

Comment: 1) "_Sorry that I cant post the images directly here I dont have enough reputation._" You don't need reputation to post the information as text. Which you should always do, when possible. 2) Why `LocationNode A = *(new LocationNode('A',1,2));` instead of `LocationNode A('A',1,2);`? Your object creation produces multiple memory leaks.

Comment: *"[...] the list changes to weird random objects from that class"* Any thought that comes with the words "random objects" when it comes to pointers should trigger a search for memory manipulation mistakes.

Comment: In response to Cheers and hth. - Alf: visual studio generated that.

Comment: I changed the object creation, still didn't fix it. Anyways, why did the way I did it produce memory leaks?

Comment: @YanayGoor attempting to use solution templates without understanding everything those templates are doing is asking for punishment

Comment: Aside *(new LocationNode('A',1,2)); bad.  bad bad bad.  really bad.  Don't do this. Ever.  Because it's bad

Comment: @YanayGoor 1) You `new` objects, and then, you immediately lose the memory address where they were allocated, so you can never `delete` them (nor do you even try to `delete` them). 2) "_I changed the object creation, still didn't fix it._" Of course it didn't fix it - memory leaks is not the issue, which impacts the code flow in a meaningful way, it.. Well.. Just leaks the memory.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Got it, thanks! didn't fix my problam though :\

Comment: Stop using operator  `new`. Stop using raw arrays[].  Use std::vector or maybe std::list, and dispense with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines like

```
LocationNode A = *(new LocationNode('A',1,2));
```

Are creating objects of type `LocationNode` on the stack. The new operation creates a new object on the heap, that is copied in your local object (see `A`, `B`, ...) and then leaked.

As you are adding local object to your `nodes` conatiner, as soon as you exit the `Init` function the data contained in the `nodes` becomes unusable for any purpose.

Change the line above in:

```
LocationNode* A = new LocationNode('A',1,2);
```

and then add them to the list using

```
nodes.push_back(A);
```

it should get rid of the 90% of your issues.

Answer (score 6):

You are pushing pointers to stack-allocated objects. These pointes become invalid right after those objects go out of scope so your `nodes` container ends up with a bunch of dangling pointers. You should populate this container with pointers to heap-allocated objects so they will be valid. And don't forget to delete them later or use smart pointers. Alternatively, you can store objects in the list by value. Note that unlike `std::vector`, `std::list` does not invalidate pointers to existing items when new items are added or removed.

```
list<LocationNode> nodes;
nodes.emplace_back('A', 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    LocationNode A = *(new LocationNode('A',1,2));
    nodes.push_back(&A);
```

What are you doing here ? You created object `new LocationNode('A',1,2)` on heap, then copy of this object is made `LocationNode A = *(new LocationNode('A',1,2));`, `A` is copy and it is created as local variable in `init` function. You push address of local variable object into `nodes` vector, but when `init` function ends all local objects are deleted, and you have in `nodes` dangling pointers - they point to objects which don't exist.
You can change to

```
LocationNode* A = new LocationNode('A',1,2);
nodes.push_back(A);
```

and remember to delete all dynamic allocated objects.